# Computing $I=\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)(3x^2+3x+1)^{1/3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve this integral and find its primitive, unfortunately I have not been successful. I made some variable changes, but I think it has become even more complicated.
My solution is as follows:
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)(3x^2+3x+1)^{1/3}}$$

$$u=x+\frac{1}{2}\iff u+\frac{1}{2}=x+1$$
$$du=dx$$
$$I=\int \frac{du}{(u+\frac{1}{2})(u^2+\frac{1}{12})^{1/3}}$$
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$I(\alpha)=\int \frac{(u-\alpha)}{(u^2-\alpha^2)(u^2+\frac{\alpha^2}{3})^{1/3}}du$$
$$I(\alpha)=\frac{1}{3^{1/3}}\int \frac{(u-\alpha)}{(u^2-\alpha^2)(3u^2+\alpha^2)^{1/3}}du$$

I hope you can help me. Regards

Comment: Have you tried partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: You can use partial fraction decomposition to get something of the form $\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{3x^2+3x+1}$. The former fraction is simple to integrate, while the latter one is much more tedious. However, you can do trig substitutions or just look up the form in an integral table as it is fairly common.

Comment: Thanks, Alan had a capture error. I have corrected it $(3x2+3x+1)^{1/3}$.

Comment: What is the context here, and are you sure you need an antiderivative rather than some integral? This is way too hard to be in a calculus class (only assuming that because of the algebra-precalc tag).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
\int \frac{dx}{( x+1)\left( 3x^{2} +3x+1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\\
=\int \frac{dx}{( x+1)\left( x^{3} +3x^{2} +3x+1-x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\\
=\int \frac{dx}{( x+1)\left(( x+1)^{3} -x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\\
=\int \frac{dx}{( x+1)^{2}\left( 1-\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\\
Let\ \frac{x}{x+1} =t\\
\frac{dx}{( x+1)^{2}} =dt\\
The\ integral\ becomes\\
\int \left( 1-t^{3}\right)^{\frac{-1}{3}} dt
\end{gather*}
Does this help in some way?

Edit: For solving the last integral, just change it to
\begin{equation*}
-\int \frac{dt}{\left( t^{3} -1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}
\end{equation*}
and make a substitution
\begin{equation*}
u=\frac{\left( t^{3} -1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{t}
\end{equation*}
After some manipulation, you will get an integrand that can be solved by partial fractions.

Comment: If this is correct then it helps immensely.

Comment: The last integral can be solved by integral-calculator.com which gives $$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt[3]{t^3-1}}{t}-1\right|\right)}{3}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{\left(t^3-1\right)^\frac{2}{3}}{t^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{t^3-1}}{t}+1\right)}{6}+\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2\sqrt[3]{t^3-1}}{t}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$ as an answer.

Comment: @Oussema Yes, I have mentioned it in aan edit.

Comment: In the "Edit", you can't simply change the overall sign (if you do so, you would get $(-1)^{-1/3}$). Just use $u = \frac{(1-t^3)^{1/3}}{t}$ to get $I = - \int \frac{u du}{1 + u^3}$.

Comment: Really really good. (+1)